# Spring cloud data flow custom application properties

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

I created a custom spring cloud data flow application.
I would like to create a stream with it and put some application properties in it, as we can add for the provided application log (0/3 properties):
[image]

I tried with `application.yml` file in `resources folder`:

```
spring:
  application:
    toto: 'titi'
```

but it didn't work.

I also tried to create some `Properties.class`

```
public class Properties {

    //public static final String PREFIX = "portin";
    private String toto;

    public Properties(String toto) {
        this.toto = toto;
    }

    public Properties() {
    }

    public String getToto() {
        return toto;
    }

    public void setToto(String toto) {
        this.toto = toto;
    }
}
```

and add the folowing declaration in `dataflow-configuration-metadata-whitelist.properties` file:

`configuration-properties.classes=com.mycompany.Properties`
but that was not a success and the aplication doesn't have any property.

I couldn't find anything relevant in documentation (I am not English speaking native so I may have misread something).

Thanks for helping

**EDIT after moving dataflow-configuration-metadata-whitelist.properties in META-INF folder**

the whitelist property files were not under META-INF folder.
Now I have this project:

[image]

but it doesn't help. The pom.xml is:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-app-starter-metadata-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>aggregate-metadata</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate-metadata</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

then I build the application with docker. Is there something docker specific to do then?
I could read the documentation but cannot see what is missing on my project

Comment: Hi, @marcesso! Would you be able to share your custom app in a GitHub repo? We could have a look to see what might be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could do the job thanks to this post: [Spring Cloud Dataflow Kubernetes get properties of jar from dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53607658/spring-cloud-dataflow-kubernetes-get-properties-of-jar-from-dockerfile)
The way I registered the app was wrong. 
Now, I add the companion metadata URI and it works

Answer (score 3):

For the custom application properties, you can make sure if you follow Spring Boot configuration properties configuration correctly. You can see some of the examples from the out of the box apps [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/file/blob/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-file/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/file/sink/FileSinkProperties.java)

I am not sure which version of SCDF do you use. If you are on the release before SCDF 2.x, then the name of the whitelist properties needs to be `spring-configuration-metadata-whitelist.properties` as the whitelist properties file with the name `dataflow-configuration-metadata-whitelist.properties` is supported only from SCDF 2.x.

Also, make sure to place the whitelist properties file into `/META-INF`  directory under classpath (src/main/resources directory) for example [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/file/blob/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-file/src/main/resources/META-INF/dataflow-configuration-metadata-whitelist.properties).

Regarding the documentation, please follow the instructions mentioned [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-stream-app-whitelisting) in the SCDF documentation.